# SWT ExpandItem Image property in Linux

Tags: java, linux, image, swt

I developed an SWT dialog in Eclipse (WindowsSO) which contains a `ExpandBar` with some `ExpandItem`s. All of these have text and image, and in Windows everything is rendered as it should be, however in linux, only the image is shown and text is not rendered.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please consider adding an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and a screenshot, so that people can help you.